# HTML5 drag and drop, make base image hidden

Tags: html

I am making drag and drop event with html5.

If you drag an image, the transparent image sticks to mouse cursor though the base image keep still.
I would like to hide the base image as if you move some real object.

So I try this code.

```
  <img src="img/tape01.png" id="img">

var img  = document.getElementById('img');

img.addEventListener('dragstart', function(evt) {
     //catch the drag event here.
         img.style.visibility = 'hidden';           

    }, true);
```

But it hides not only base image but dragged image.

Comment: Are they, by chance, both given the ID of `img`? Please include your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

This is the standard behaviour of a html5 browser to keep two images of the draggable object on screen to remind the user the starting position and current position of the dragging object before its drop event is completed.

In your example, setting the draggable object 'img' be invisible will make the two images of it be invisible at the same time.

Comment: So is it impossible to hide the original image when dragging??